# Bulk update single field with gorm CreateInBatches

Tags: go-gorm

I'm using gorm to update multiple records like this,

```
if tx := c.Database.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{UpdateAll: true}).CreateInBatches(snapshots, 100); tx.Error != nil {
    logrus.Errorf("failed to update database: %v", tx.Error)
    return
}
```

Since only one field in the `[]*StructName` is being updated, is it possible to use CreateInBatches with UpdateColumn method?

I mean, the value is already stored in each struct, I just want gorm to ignore all other fields